# Google Play - reduce update size

Tags: android, google-play

I am developing a [game](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.avitus.firstflight) for Android it´s currently in open beta and I have published a few updates already. I noticed that you always need to download/update the whole app, which is pretty bad for bigger games.

**My Question:** Can you kinda split-up parts of the game so the user only needs to download smaller parts? (Like a resource-pack, config-files,...)

---

**Are Expension Files the answer?** As far as I understood them, they are meant for really big games which need more space than 50MB and are meant to be used mainly for big files.
Is it possible to make an Expansion Fack just for config files, and only update that EF, making updates smaller?

**Edit:** (See [here](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html#Rules))

> You cannot issue an update to your application by changing the expansion files alone—you must upload a new APK to update your app.

If I am understood this correctly, I can´t update an Expension File without also updating the APK, which the user would need to download. (And that´s what I am trying to avoid)

---

**Manually downloading files**
I could check if there is a new version of config-files available on my server, and if yes, download them before every launch of the game. Would that be a possible solution?

Comment: A lot of games I've played involved downloading a smaller app from the Play Store as a base. Once you've downloaded that and you open the game it downloads the actual content within the game itself. Perhaps this way you can control updates better?

Comment: I think most of these app actually download Expension Files, might be wrong though - see [here](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html#Downloading)

Comment: The same page mentions something about patches for the expansion file. Is that something you're looking for?

Comment: I don´t think so: "You cannot issue an update to your application by changing the expansion files alone—you must upload a new APK to update your app." -> If you update an Expension File, you also need to update your APK, which the user needs to download.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Google Play store already does this automatically for you; it is a feature called Delta Updates.

This only works on devices running Android 4.1 and up, but if you look at the [platform numbers](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html), 4.1 and up is already installed on just over a third of the devices accessing the store.

I wouldn't spend too much time on trying to implement this manually, as in the future (once more people are on 4.1+) it will be pointless.

That said, if you do find a trivial way of implementing it then by all means do so, I just wouldn't waste a lot of time trying to find a solution for a problem that is already solved (for newer devices). Most people playing games will upgrade their devices sooner or later.

**Edit:**
I think this may if fact be on devices running 4.0+.
I switched from a 2.3 device (which did not have it) to a 4.1 device which did and assumed (incorrectly) that it was a 4.1+ feature. So that means that more than 60% of android users already have this feature :)

Also, an easy way to test if this is working is to check the progress bar in the notification while downloading an update to a large app. For some reason, the notification progress bar shows the progress of the delta download, while the play store progress bar shows it for the full download.

Comment: Nice, never heard about this. Exactly what I wanted.
Btw, a link would be nice, [this](http://www.androidcentral.com/what-are-delta-updates-and-why-youll-forget-about-it-tomorrow) for example

Comment: Are you sure it's 4.1 and up? I swear my Galaxy S2 running 4.0.3 also gets delta updates.

Comment: No problem, I just never found an "official" posting about it which is why I did not link to it. A google search for 'Android Delta Updates' will show multiple sources :)

Comment: @Logan Dam - it used to be on 4.1 only, but Google may have changed that (if they figured out a way). They absolutely "could" do it since (as far as I know) all of the functionality to do so is in the play store apk (which gets updated on all devices) and on the server side. The play store app could just download the delta and create a full apk before installing - which would actually mean they could implement it on any android version (if they wanted).